# undefined style

Tags: javascript

I have homework from university, classic 15 puzzle. I have problem with those two styles. Here is the code that i have problem

```
function siirra_pala(pala) {
 var palaRivi = parseInt(pala.style.top) / palanKoko;
 var palaSarake = parseInt(pala.style.left) / palanKoko;
}
```

Error code is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of undefined".

If it helps: 
siirra_pala(pala) is move_tile(tile)
palaRivi is tileRow and palaSarake is tileColumn
palanKoko is tileSize.

I have palanKoko set to 100. And style is defined in:

```
function muodosta_palat(pelialue) {
for (var y = 0; y < 4; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        if (!(x === tyhja_paikka.x && y === tyhja_paikka.y)) {
            var pala = document.createElement('div');
            pala.id = 'pala' + x + y;
            pala.textContent = 4 * y + x + 1;
            pala.style.left = x * palanKoko + 'px';
            pala.style.top = y * palanKoko + 'px';
            pala.className = 'pala';
            pelialue.appendChild(pala);
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more code, please tell which one. Thank You

@Bergi:

```
window.onload = function () {

muodosta_palat(document.getElementById('pelialue'));
var palat = document.querySelectorAll(".pala");
document.getElementById('sekoitusnappi').onclick = sekoita;
for (var i = 0; i < palat.length; i++) {
    palat[i].addEventListener("click", siirra_pala);
    palat[i].addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);
    palat[i].addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut);
}
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you're missing `pala.style = {}` before you start populating the style properties.

Comment: Where do you call `siirra_pala` and with what argument?

Comment: @OmriAharon: No, `pala` is a div and has a `.style` property already

Comment: @Bergi added code to original post

Comment: @muti: Ah, you're using it as an event handler. What do you think it will be called with?

Comment: @Bergi It should move piece when i click it. When i click, it should get tile (= pala) position from style (x-axis / size, y-axis / size) and give that tile row and column

Comment: @muti: Yes, but event handlers are called with an event argument, not the pala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error it would seem `pala` is undefined (not set, doesn't exist), at least not in the scope of that function.

Variable `pala` is created within a function, and it's only known **in this function**. What you want to do is capture the click event, and pass what was clicked to the function.

If you change call to the function..

```
palat[i].addEventListener("click", function () { siirra_pala(this) });
```

the reference should be ok.

Comment: The fix will do it. However, the first line you wrote is incorrect - `pala` actually is defined according to the error, as the error says `top of undefined`, which means the `style` property is undefined.

Comment: Actually, after a few tests: This seems to be because when @multi bound the eventlistener to the function, without parameter, the event got sent as a parameter `MouseEvent {dataTransfer: null..`. So while `pala`was something, it was not was what expected. jsfiddle.net/tv22wydd

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
palat[i].addEventListener("click", siirra_pala);
```

the parameter passed to `siirra_pala` is the click event, not the clicked element. You should modify your function to either select the clicked element property from the event object or simply use `this`.

See this:

```js
document.getElementById('x').addEventListener("click", handler);

function handler(e) {
  console.log(e);      // full event object
  console.log(this);   // clicked element
  this.style.background = "#aaa";
}
```

```css
#x {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
```

---

So the fix for your function would be something like this:

```
function siirra_pala(pala) {
  var palaRivi = parseInt(this.style.top) / palanKoko;
  var palaSarake = parseInt(this.style.left) / palanKoko;
}
```

(bear in mind that this function is not very useful)